# fastjsonapi serializer error | NameError (uninitialized constant <my serializer class>)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nameerror, fastjsonapi

I have just added the gem '**fast_jsonapi**' for serialization of my rails api data into json.

I have a model class of Website created. Below is the serializer class I want to access data through:

```
class WebsiteSerializer
  include FastJsonapi::ObjectSerializer
  attributes :name, :image_url, :slug

  has_many :reviews
end
```

So, I run the command below in the rails console.

```
$ web = Website.first
$ WebsiteSerializer.new(web).serialized_json
```

It gives the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
        2: from (irb):14
        1: from (irb):15:in `rescue in irb_binding'
NameError (uninitialized constant WebsiteSerializer)
```

Comment: where is the serializer located in the project structure?

Comment: Make sure the file is named `website_serializer` and under `app/serializers` or some other folder name

Answer (score 1):

The `fast_jsonapi` serializer is no longer supported, use `jsonapi-serializer` instead:

[Jsonapi-serializer](https://github.com/jsonapi-serializer/jsonapi-serializer)